# Intuition on size of fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was wondering if the size of the fundamental group, when finite, captures how many 'distinct' (non-homotopic) loops (**$1$-dimensional cycles**) there are in the space. Is that the correct intuition?

I'm asking since in one of Hatcher's examples (Example 2.38 in *Algebraic Topology*), he computes the size in order to demonstrate that the space is acyclic, and did so *after* describing the fundamental group, which was clearly not trivial (he had also already shown that all reduced homology groups are $0$). This makes it seem like he wanted to show more -- that the number of 'distinct' cycles ($1$-d cycles for that matter) is, in fact, quite large. Would that be correct intuition?

Comment: Which particular example in Hatcher's book are you referring to?

Comment: "Loops" and "$1$-dimensional cycles" do not mean the same thing! The first phrase refers to the fundamental group and the second phrase refers to first homology.

Comment: @LeeMosher Example 2.38. He describes there the presentation of the fundamental group, which is already non-trivial. So why does he bother computing its size? (i.e. what is he trying to emphasize there?)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I know - but isn't it the case that in $1$-d we can take a loop and 
 describe it as a $1$-cycle (and vice-versa)? e.g. by describing a corresponding map from the singular $1$-simplex that traces the exact same image of the loop? (or something in that line of thought? not too sure about formalizing this...). Both would be continuously tracing the same image. So can't they be viewed as the same thing in the given space?

Comment: @Anon This approach can be used to construct a homomorphism from $\pi_1(X)$ to $H_1(X)$ – but this morphism is usually not iso, so it's rather dangerous to think of cycles and loops as the same. I'm also not true what do you mean by "size" of the fundamental group (unless your group is finite).

Comment: @radekzak Thanks - good to know. Maybe in this example they are iso? Yes - I am referring to finite fundamental groups only here. Specifically this one has size $120$. Just trying to figure out what the significance of the size is in his discussion of this acyclic space.

Comment: Hatcher's main point in this discussion of the fundamental group is to show that it is nontrivial, and therefore to show that the space is not contractible. The particular size if the fundamental group is a side comment, not central to what he's doing.

Comment: The homology groups are all zero (the space is acyclic). In particular, $H_1$ and $\pi_1$ are not isomorphic. By the way, he is not computing the size of the fundamental group to demonstrate that the space is acyclic. The acyclicity is dealt with in the first paragraph of the example, the nontrivially of the fundamental group in the second paragraph.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Isn't the representation itself of $\langle a,b | a^5b^{-3}, b^3(ab)^{-2}\rangle$ sufficient for it to be non-trivial?

Comment: This is related to the word problem in group theory: it is undecidable whether a group is trivial, given a presentation of that group. So to determine whether a group is nontrivial, it is a good idea, and frequently necessary, to do more than just give a particular presentation.

Comment: Regarding your most recent comment, having used the presentation $\langle a,b \mid a^5 b^{-3}, b^3 (ab)^{-2} \rangle$ of the fundamental group to construct a nontrivial homomorphism onto the symmetry group of a dodecahedron, it follows that the fundamental group is nontrivial. Keep in mind, that presentation in and of itself is not enough to determine nontriviality (as said in the previous comment of @JohnPalmieri). But as this example illustrates, the presentation can be a useful tool for constructing nontrivial homomorphisms.

Comment: Regarding your questions about Hatcher's emphasis in this example, you seem to be wondering about the last two sentences in which he outlines a proof that the fundamental group has order 120. The wording of these sentences should be a hint to the reader regarding their import: "It is not hard to see that... With more work one can ...". These sentences are directed to a curious reader who is willing to explore this example more deeply, once the central point has been achieved. For instance, a reader might wonder: *Knowing that $\pi_1$ is nontrivial, what exactly is its order?*